# Create a InternetAddress and set it to RecipientType BCC

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I've created a jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress

```
InternetAddress system = new InternetAddress("nunyi@gmail.com");
```

but there is no set to set it as  `RecipientType BCC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InternetAddress is an object used to define address and has no property of type. However you can set the type when added this address to your message:

InternetAddress system = new InternetAddress("nunyi@gmail.com");
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, system);